# Learn C or C++ for php extensions

Tags: php, c++, c

I have been programming for a while now in php and want to broaden my knowledge of programming by learning another language whilst hopefully in the process getting better at php also.

One way to do this would be to look at writing extensions for php which would be in c or c++.

Can anyone say which language would be better to focus on for this task?

I know the languages are very similar and that c++ allows for object orientated code but would c be faster and more suited to php extensions?

Answer (score 2):

This might help you: http://devzone.zend.com/article/1021 (with more than the answer to you question).

> This tutorial assumes basic
>   familiarity with both the PHP language
>   and the language the PHP interpreter
>   is written in: **C**.

<del>So you can't use C++.</del>
If you want to use C++ you should take a look at this [article](http://devzone.zend.com/article/4486).
*Thank you Christoph for pointing this out.*

Comment: of course you can use C++ to write PHP extensions: just create a C wrapper API; see eg http://devzone.zend.com/article/4486 on the same website

Answer (score -2):

The php interpreter is written in C, and the APIs are all in C already.  C is the only choice in this case.

Plus, you already know object oriented paradigms from learning php it sounds like, so why not jump into the procedural programming world with C?

Comment: not true: you can use any language which supports the C calling convention; assuming gcc, this includes C++, Objective-C, Fortran and Ada

Comment: This is definitely not true. Many languages support this. You could even use C# or Java, if you really wanted to.